# I can not change the version of tensorflow in venv jupyter-notebook

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, python-venv

I run virtual environment `python -m venv test` , after I register kernel `ipython kernel install --user --name=test`, I run jupyter-notebook and choose kernel 'test'.
Run code

```
!pip install tensorflow==1.14
import tensorflow as tf
#print(tf.VERSION)
print(tf.version.VERSION)
```

return 2.9.1

But after I check in console `(test) c:\example>python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"`, return 1.14.0

Could anyone explain the reason why jupyter-notebook does not change the version of the tensorflow?

Comment: check kernel->change kernel, and see whether you have selected the right kernel. If you don't find other options, you may need to install Jupiter notebook for the current env.

Comment: Please help us know which python version is installed in your system?

Answer (score 0):

Along with Tensorflow, Jupyter notebook also needs a downgraded compatible Python version .

Usage of TF2.0 and above is recommended in WSL2/Linux .

Follow these steps while you use TF in Windows.

#### Install NuGet

1. Download `nuget.exe` from https://www.nuget.org/downloads choose the
   latest from Windows x86 Commandline.
2. Move the executable to a “safe
   folder”
3. Add the folder to Windows PATH Environment Variables.

#### Install a compatible python version

```
nuget.exe install python -ExcludeVersion -OutputDirectory
```

#### Create the Virtualenv

```
virtualenv --python=C:/Users/SessionUser/.nuget/packages/python/3.5.2/tools/python.exe env
```

#### Activate venv

#### install TF

```
pip install tensorflow
```

#### Add env to ipykernel

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=env
```